# My XML file won't load.I've tried everything. Does anyone know why?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, data-science

```
from lxml import objectify
import pandas as pd

xml = objectify.parse(open('C:/Users/admin/Downloads/XMLData2.xml'))
root = xml.getroot() # root contains 4 'record' nodes
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Number', 'String', 'Boolean'))

for i in range(0,4):
obj = root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()
row = dict(zip(['Number', 'String', 'Boolean'], 
               [obj[0].text, obj[1].text, 
                obj[2].text]))
row_s = pd.Series(row)
row_s.name = i
df = df.append(row_s)

search = pd.DataFrame.duplicated(df)
print (df)
print
print (search[search == True])
```

This is the error i get --->  No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/admin/Downloads/XMLData2.xml'

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are new to python.

The code you are trying have no errors.
So the possible issues lies in your path.

Please check the address of the xml file and try again.
In case you have trouble finding out the address.

1. Go to the folder containing the file.
2. Right click on the file and click on properties.
3. You will be able to see the file location.
4. Copy it, add on the file name and replace the \ to /.

Comment: Yeah I did that. Its in a zip folder in my downloads. I copied the complete path like I wrote above. it still doesnt work. idk why

Comment: You need to extract the file first, then use the path of the fie from extracted folder. Regards.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help. If it solved your problem, you can mark it as answered/useful. Thanks.